# Help Understanding a Sentence

Tags: meaning

I'm having trouble understanding the following sentence from a small Pokémon comic I found online.

**それに本当に自分と同じ色だったら同族嫌悪して自分から近づくはずがない.**

Here's a link to the comic for context: https://e621.net/posts/569425 (The ad at the top of the page may be NSFW.)

I'm able to parse the sentence just fine, but when I put it all together it doesn't make sense to me.

Here's my translation: **In addition, if they really are the same color as myself, it's impossible for me to approach them because I hate the same type as myself.**

The reason why it doesn't make sense to me is because the Pikachu already tried to approach the Lucario in the first panel, so why are they thinking it would be impossible to approach now?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ～だったら～はずがない is counterfactual hypothesis (事実に反する仮定).
"If... were..., ... wouldn't have done...", implying "As... is not..., ... did..."

So it's like:

それに本当に自分と同じ色**だったら**同族嫌悪して自分から近づく**はずがない**。
i.e. 「本当に自分と同じ色では**ないので**、自分から近づい**た**。」
（「自分から近づいたということは、本当に自分と同じ色ではないということだ。」）

It means:

"In addition / Also, if they really **were** the same color as myself, I **would never have** approached them, because I hate the same type as myself."
i.e. "I **approached** them because they are **not** really the same color as myself."
(The fact that I approached them shows/proves that they are not the same color as me.)

It's also clear from the previous line:
あの色は人を引き寄せてる。自分とは**違う色なんだ**。
"(Unlike mine,) Their color attracts others. It's a **different color** from mine."